# How to access current route meta fields in common javascript module - VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have following route in my application:

```js
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  scrollBehavior: () => ({ y: 0 }),
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: HomePage, meta: { pageType: 'home'} },
  ],
});
```

and have on common js module:

```js
const trackEvent = {
  getFields: () => {
  //here need to access meta fields(pageType) of current route. how is it possible ?
  }
}
export default trackEvent;
```

i want to access meta field in common module. how is it possible ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The `meta` property is accessible via `this.$route.meta` on a Vue instance. Just pass that to the `getFields` method.

```js
export default {
  created() {
    let meta = getFields(this.$route.meta);
  }
}
```

```js
getFields: (meta) => {
  console.log(meta);

  return meta.fields.pageType; // not sure what you're trying to return exactly
}
```

If you can't pass in the current route, you'll need to import the `router` object and get the current route from that:

```js
import router from 'path/to/your/router'

const trackEvent = {
  getFields: () => {
    let meta = router.currentRoute.meta;
    console.log(meta);

    return meta.fields.pageType; // not sure what you're trying to return exactly
  }
}
export default trackEvent;
```

Comment: i have some use case where i direct need to access meta field in JS Module without passing meta field from component.

Comment: Okay, you'll need to import the `router` object in that case. See my edit.